# Exporting SWT Image into PDF using Java iText API

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have a an SWT image I want to export this image into a pdf file using iText API.
I have tried saving this image on the disk and then using the path of image to export
it to the pdf, this takes lots of time to generate the pdf.
I have also tried converting the SWT image into AWT image and then exporting it into the
pdf, this approach takes even more time to generate pdf.
Another approach I have been trying is to convert the raw data of image into 
jpeg byteArrayOutputStream using ImageLoader Object as shown below :

```
ImageLoader tempLoader = new ImageLoader();
tempLoader.data = new ImageData[] {
    image.getImageData()                    
};
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
tempLoader.save(bos, SWT.IMAGE_JPEG);
```

Now I am using this ByteArrayOutputStream as input to

```
OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(selectedPathAndName);
Document document = new Document();    
document.setMargins(0,0,0,0);
document.setPageSize(new Rectangle(0,0,width,height));
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outStream);
document.open(); 
com.itextpdf.text.Image pdfImage = com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(bos.toByteArray());
document.add(pdfImage); 
document.close();
```

This generates pdf files with the width and height I have set, but the page seems to be empty.
Any suggestions or any other approach is most welcome.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

It looks your page sizes are zero, try setting them to something like **A4** in the constructor.

`Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);`